# how to disable unused services without using Gui?

Tags: 12.10, embedded-system, linaro

I want to disable some unused services like bluetooth service, pulse audio service, speech dispatcher services  for embedded platform.

I have beagle bone black and Xilinx Zynq-7000 All Programmable SoC ZC702 Evaluation Kit. I'm using linaro-ubuntu 12.10 distro, so how to i disable some above services with using terminal? Thanks.